# How can I make a particular element last thing to be reduced when the window is resized?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to create a central content box that functions in actually in the same way that Stackoverflow's does. If the user reduces the window size by dragging the edge of their browser, the main content of the page isn't reduced until after the margins and other elements have been.

So I have this for my HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
<div>Title</div>
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="filler1.html">filler1</a>
<a href="filler2.html">filler2</a>
</div>


<div class="content">
 testing123
</div>
```

And for my CSS:

```
body {
margin:0; // Because I have a navigation bar at the top that wouldn't quite reach
// the full length of the page
margin-top: 100px; //to stop other elements covering the navigation.
background-color: #ffffee
}

.content {
background-color: white;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
max-width: 1500px;
min-width: 1500px;
left: 100px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give it a max-width and center it:

```
.content {
    ...
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4x0w3c4h/)